# Does Python have an inline statement?

Tags: python, inline

Does python have something similar to `inline` in C?

If not, how can I speed up the execution of a function?

Comment: Python is interpreted, so everything is equally "inline" in some sense.  You'll need to give a more specific example if you want help speeding something up.

Comment: you mean lambdas? use Cython or something? optimizations are unique to program function...

Comment: FYI (1) Inlining does not necessarily improve performance. (2) `inline` does not mean anything to today's C compilers - they simply ignore it.

Comment: you should probably measure carefully before optimizing whatever comes up as the first bottleneck.

Answer (score 7):

No, python does not have such a statement.

However, if the overhead of a function call is a problem for you, using a scripting language like Python is the wrong choice. Consider moving the relevant parts into a C extension. In case that's an option for you have a look at [Cython](http://www.cython.org/).

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. However there are several mechanisms for speeding Python execution, for instance you could call native C code from a Python program, for example using [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/):

> The Boost Python Library is a framework for interfacing Python and C++. It allows you to quickly and seamlessly expose C++ classes functions and objects to Python, and vice-versa, using no special tools -- just your C++ compiler. It is designed to wrap C++ interfaces non-intrusively, so that you should not have to change the C++ code at all in order to wrap it, making Boost.Python ideal for exposing 3rd-party libraries to Python. The library's use of advanced metaprogramming techniques simplifies its syntax for users, so that wrapping code takes on the look of a kind of declarative interface definition language (IDL).

Answer (score 1):

There is a library you can download called [Weave](http://www.scipy.org/Weave/) from scipy that allows you to inline c or c++ code into your python code.  That will speed it up.

However python does not in itself have an inline function.

There are other libraries that are designed to speed up computation like scipy, numpy, I think matplotlib is a pretty good library.  Also there is iPython for parallel computing.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an equivalent inline feature in Python.

The best thing you can do to speed up a function it to examine the algorithm assuming you have exhausted idiomatic language features (such as list comprehension etc).

Answer (score 0):

Python will optimize the code for you, but you don't have any influence in how it does. To speed up the *loadtimes* of about any python code, you can compile it to bytecode before execution.